# Joomla jshopping maxlength of TinyMCE (html code)

Tags: joomla, tinymce, maxlength, character-limit

I'm using jshopping to post product. I click on Toggle editor (HTML viewer) and input about 12.500 chars, after saving it was saved about 6000 chars.
How to increase chars limit ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check the database table field and increase the value if needed. If it doesn't work you have to search in the jshopping core files to find the line that trim the text.

Comment: I edited in description_en_GB from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT. Now it works! thank you @emmanuel

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!